# Is there any other way to refresh div to all members without timer?

Tags: php, timer, chat

i have a chat script made from scratch. Everything works fine, but i have a fell that my site is getting too many requests from a timer. I can see that when i Inspect Element on google chrome (Network), the timer is calling function every single second. I need that, to make my chat update for all members, but i want to make it other way if it's possible.

```
function Chat_Send(){
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');
    var value=$.trim($("#message").val()); //If input is empty
    if(value.length>0){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'load.php?chat_send',
            data: "message=" + $('#message').val(),
        });
        $('#message').val('');
        $('#message').attr("disabled", "true");
        $('#mybutton').attr("disabled", "true");
        setTimeout(enableMe, 1000);
        $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).height() }, "fast"); return false;
    }
}
function Chat_Refresh(){
    $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).height() }, "fast"); return false;
    <?php
    // Set status to 0
    $sql_chat = "UPDATE users SET status='0'";
    $stmt_chat = $handler->prepare($sql_chat);
    $stmt_chat->execute();
    ?>
}
setInterval('test()', 1000);
function test(){
    $('#chatbox').load('load.php?chat_refresh');
    $("#online-users-text").load(location.href+ ' #online-users-text');
    <?php
    $query_chat = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    while($ch = $query_chat->fetch()){
        if($ch['status'] == 1){
            ?> Chat_Refresh(); <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
}
```

You can test it here monkstudio.biz/chat ,login to see the chat:
Username: **Demo**
Password: **demo123**

Comment: use websocket http://socketo.me/

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez I know for that, but then i must search for a host and other things. It's a new thing to me, so it will take me awhile to figure it out how to make: all members online, rooms, pm...etc